# flutter build won't find a dependecy but when i copy the link to my browser it's at the same location

Tags: gradle, flutter

So I've just started flutter with zero experience in mobile development .
and i just created a new project and when i try build it with `flutter build apk` it give's me this

```
Initializing gradle...                                              1.2s
Resolving dependencies...                                               
* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "/media/OLB/Shared Media/Code Work Space/Visual Studio
Code/flutter_test1/android/gradlew" exited abnormally:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find builder.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:3.2.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/3.2.1/builder-3.2.1.jar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
  Command: /media/OLB/Shared Media/Code Work Space/Visual Studio Code/flutter_test1/android/gradlew
  app:properties


Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
```

but when i copy the provided link

```
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/3.2.1/builder-3.2.1.jar
```

the file is their !

---

`flutter doctor -v`

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.5.4-hotfix.2, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 1.5.4-hotfix.2 at /media/OBL/Shared Media/Code Work Space/Android/flutter
    • Framework revision 7a4c33425d (4 weeks ago), 2019-04-29 11:05:24 -0700
    • Engine revision 52c7a1e849
    • Dart version 2.3.0 (build 2.3.0-dev.0.5 a1668566e5)


[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /media/OBL/Shared Media/Code Work Space/Android/
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = /media/OBL/Shared Media/Code Work Space/Android/
    • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = /media/OBL/Shared Media/Code Work Space/Android/sdk/
    • Java binary at: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-8u212-b03-0ubuntu1.18.04.1-b03)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions).

[✓] VS Code (version 1.34.0)
    • VS Code at /usr/share/code
    • Flutter extension version 3.0.2

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

I know their is no AS but i'v download all required stuff through the Android sdk directly , please help and thanx in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about it but a friend advised me to refresh the dependencies manually from `/project/android/gradlew` and it worked !! like this

```
gradlew --refresh-dependencies
```

and it worked like a charm .

Answer (score 0):

As the Flutter documentation says, Android Studio is required: "Flutter relies on a full installation of Android Studio to supply its Android platform dependencies."

So you have to install Android Studio as well.